# Diffrent Prefab in Network Lobby Manager Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I want to let each client to select their player prefab in lobby and when game start I want to instantiate selected prefab for client. I defined variable in LobbyManager but it's not working. It's always with the same host. How can I solve this?

Here is my code:

```
 public override GameObject OnLobbyServerCreateGamePlayer(NetworkConnection conn, short playerControllerId)
    {
        Debug.LogError(playerPrefabIndex + "Ins Index");
        GameObject playerPrefab = (GameObject)Instantiate(spawnPrefabs[playerPrefabIndex]);
        NetworkServer.Spawn(playerPrefab);
        return playerPrefab;
    }
```

Comment: What happens when you remove NetworkServer.Spawn(playerPrefab)?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I instantiate prefab without model and pass prefab id via syncvar then call  SetModelById() in script attached to player's object  on all clients.